# Error when more than one item to List of Objects using JAXB's @XmlAnyElement and XmlAdapter

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have been attempting to adapt the code presented in this article:
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/xmlanyelement-and-xmladapter.html

When I run as a stand-alone Java program ( like this - https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20120213/blob/master/src/main/java/blog/anyelement/adapted/Demo.java ), everything works well.

I have put the full source and project onto Bitbucket here:  https://bitbucket.org/johnson_shawn/stackoverflow-21471310

It's a bare-minimum Java project with a Dynamic Web facet - no classes added for Web-Inf/lib, everything is "provided" by JBoss AS 7.1 runtime.

I'm really more focused on the marshalling, so I adapted the program slightly to output a simple model which works fine...However, when I wrap the same code in a JAX-RS service, I get an ugly error that I can't quite figure out.

This is the service + main method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

@Path("/api/v2")
public class TestService  {


    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(value = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
    public TestModel getModel() {
            TestModel docket = getSampleModel();
            return docket;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestModel.class, LabelValue.class);
        LabelValueAdapter adapter = new LabelValueAdapter(jc);

        TestModel docket = getSampleModel();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAdapter(adapter);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(docket, System.out);
    }


    private static TestModel getSampleModel() {
        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        List<LabelValue> metadata = new ArrayList<LabelValue>();
        metadata.add(new LabelValue("Distilled Water", "Deer Park"));
        metadata.add(new LabelValue("Mineral Water", "Mountain Stream"));
        metadata.add(new LabelValue("Purified Water", "Mr. Water"));
        model.setMetadata(metadata);
        return model;
    }

}
```

The LabelValue class is essentially the same as Blaise Doughan's original Parameter class.  Any idea what might be wrong at the RESTEasy level to cause this issue?

Here is the error:

> 21:02:19,959 INFO  [stdout] 2014-01-30 21:02:19,956
>   [http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1] WARN 
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher (Log4jLogger.java:135) -
>   Failed executing GET /api/v2/test 21:02:19,959 INFO  [stdout]
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBMarshalException:
>   javax.xml.bind.MarshalException 21:02:19,959 INFO  [stdout]  - with
>   linked exception: 21:02:19,959 INFO  [stdout]
>   [com.sun.istack.SAXException2 21:02:19,959 INFO  [stdout]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException] 21:02:19,959 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.writeTo(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:148)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:117)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.write(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:104)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:123)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:250)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeJaxrsResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:585)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:506)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:155)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212)
>   21:02:19,960 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.custom.GuiceResteasyFilterDispatcher.doFilter(GuiceResteasyFilterDispatcher.java:118)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   21:02:19,961 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   21:02:19,962 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
>   21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
>   21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
>   21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout] Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>   21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout]  - with linked exception: 21:02:19,963
>   INFO  [stdout] [com.sun.istack.SAXException2 21:02:19,963 INFO 
>   [stdout] java.lang.NullPointerException] 21:02:19,963 INFO  [stdout]
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:326)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:74)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.writeTo(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:144)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   ... 32 more 21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]
>   Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2 21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]    at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:247)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:262)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister$ListIteratorImpl.next(AdaptedLister.java:115)
>   21:02:19,964 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:107)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   ... 35 more 21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister.getAdapter(AdaptedLister.java:68)
>   21:02:19,965 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister.access$000(AdaptedLister.java:55)
>   21:02:19,966 INFO  [stdout]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister$ListIteratorImpl.next(AdaptedLister.java:113)
>   21:02:19,966 INFO  [stdout]   ... 42 more 21:02:19,956 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] Failed executing GET
>   /api/v2/test:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBMarshalException:
>   javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2 java.lang.NullPointerException]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.writeTo(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:148)
>   [resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:117)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.write(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:104)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyWriterContextImpl.java:123)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:250)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeJaxrsResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:585)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:506)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:155)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     at
>   com.custom.GuiceResteasyFilterDispatcher.doFilter(GuiceResteasyFilterDispatcher.java:118)
>   [classes:]    at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
>   [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2 java.lang.NullPointerException]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:74)
>   [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.writeTo(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:144)
>   [resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.3.Final.jar:]     ... 32 more Caused by:
>   com.sun.istack.SAXException2 java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:247)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:262)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister$ListIteratorImpl.next(AdaptedLister.java:115)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
>     ... 35 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister.getAdapter(AdaptedLister.java:68)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister.access$000(AdaptedLister.java:55)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister$ListIteratorImpl.next(AdaptedLister.java:113)
>     ... 42 more

Comment: sounds like a error in your deployment or a class/jar incompatibility

Comment: what jars did u added to classpath ?? tell me

Comment: To keep things simple, I created a new project and uploaded to bitbucket.  The only dependency is JBoss 7 - all the classes used for compile are 'provided' at runtime by JBoss.